# [Jquery ]Enable the button that was disabled. By the button which was added

Tags: jquery

Here I have two button, each has a parent class called card with its own (data-addid). the buttons themselves have a class of btn. When the button is clicked, it is disabled. and adds a class of cout to class of proCO. the class of cout has the same (data-addid) from the button that was clicked.

How can i use the new buttons to re-enable only the button that has added it. Without enabling both only when the respective id matches

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $(`.btn`).click((event)=>{
    let addbtn = $(event.currentTarget);
    let id = addbtn.parents(`.card`).attr(`data-addid`);
    $(`.proCO`).append(`<div  class="cout" data-addid="${id}"><button  class="remove clear">put back </button></div>`);
    
    
inCart(id);

  
    $(`.remove`).click((event)=>{
      let move = $(event.currentTarget);
      let moveID = move.parents(`.cout`);
      

putback(moveID);
      //remove end
    });
    
 clearCart(id);
   //add end
  });
  //dr end
});

function inCart(id){
 let incart = $(`.card[data-addid="${id}"]`);
 $.each(incart,(k,v)=>{
    let inbtn = $(v).find(`.btn`)
    inbtn.prop("disabled", true)
   putback(id)
 })
  //incart end
}

  function putback(moveID){
    $(moveID).remove();
      
    //put back end
  }



function clearCart(id){
    $(`#clear`).click((event)=>{
      $(`.cout`).remove();
      $(`.btn`).prop("disabled", false)
    })
    // clear end 
  }
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="container text-center">
   <div class="proCard">
   <div class="card" data-addid="1" >
    <button class="btn" >btn1</button>
  </div>
      <div class="card" data-addid="2" >
    <button class="btn" >btn2</button>
  </div>
     
  </div>

      <hr />
      <h1>In/out</h1>

  <div class="proCO">
  </div>
      <hr />
      <h1>clear</h1>
      <div class="cartTotal">
       
       <button id="clear">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <script src="./js/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `data-addid` for the `cout` element before remove .. Try this

```
function putback(moveID){
    var get_id = $(moveID).attr('data-addid');
    $(moveID).remove();
    $(`.card[data-addid="${get_id}"] .btn`).prop("disabled", false);
    //put back end
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $(`.btn`).click((event)=>{
    let addbtn = $(event.currentTarget);
    let id = addbtn.parents(`.card`).attr(`data-addid`);
    $(`.proCO`).append(`<div  class="cout" data-addid="${id}"><button  class="remove clear">put back </button></div>`);
    
    
inCart(id);

  
    $(`.remove`).click((event)=>{
      let move = $(event.currentTarget);
      let moveID = move.parents(`.cout`);
      

putback(moveID);
      //remove end
    });
    
 clearCart(id);
   //add end
  });
  //dr end
});

function inCart(id){
 let incart = $(`.card[data-addid="${id}"]`);
 $.each(incart,(k,v)=>{
    let inbtn = $(v).find(`.btn`)
    inbtn.prop("disabled", true)
   putback(id)
 })
  //incart end
}

  function putback(moveID){
        var get_id = $(moveID).attr('data-addid');
        $(moveID).remove();
        $(`.card[data-addid="${get_id}"] .btn`).prop('disabled' , false);
        //put back end
      }


function clearCart(id){
    $(`#clear`).click((event)=>{
      $(`.cout`).remove();
      $(`.btn`).prop("disabled", false)
    })
    // clear end 
  }
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="container text-center">
   <div class="proCard">
   <div class="card" data-addid="1" >
    <button class="btn" >btn1</button>
  </div>
      <div class="card" data-addid="2" >
    <button class="btn" >btn2</button>
  </div>
     
  </div>

      <hr />
      <h1>In/out</h1>

  <div class="proCO">
  </div>
      <hr />
      <h1>clear</h1>
      <div class="cartTotal">
       
       <button id="clear">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <script src="./js/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I was able to obtain the id. while applied even without the remove class. it unfortunately  still does not enable the button.

Comment: @DevDub You disabled the `.btn` which inside the `data-addid` element .. then just add `.btn` to the selector .. see updated answer